# Can I use a larger garage door motor as a substitute for proper springs?

Tags: garage-door-opener

I have a wooden garage door which is very old and heavy. The cable is broken. A spring was broken sometime back and I got the spring replaced with a new one. The guy did a poor job and the spring does not carry much weight. At this point will the replacement with a higher capacity motor (1-1/4 hp) for the existing 1/3 hp motor be worthy? Are there any parts that would not work with a different capacity motor?

What other things would I need to watch during the replacement process?

Comment: In addition to what jwh20 said, just no. Even a larger motor shouldn't have to actually lift the door (just move it), and you're likely to wreck the track and other things by expecting it to do so. This happens easily, especially with a side-to-side imbalance, and _it's dangerous_. Fix the springs.

Comment: *"The guy did a poor job and the spring does not carry much weight."* Does this mean that with the opener disengaged you can not  lift the door manually because the spring is not providing enough lift ? You have physically ascertained this yourself ? **Did you ask the guy to come back and re-tension the springs or did you try to operate the door with out the springs being set properly ?** Why do you think trying to hack the opener motor is a better idea then having the door springs and cable put in proper working order ?

Answer (score 4):

### Absolutely Not!!!

Garage door openers are not designed or intended to hoist the door by brute force - the door should always be adjusted for easy manual operation before the opener is connected, or in the event of the opener failing, a power outge, etc.

This is primarily a safety issue (getting killed or injured by an improperly balanced door crashing down) rather than a "how powerful is the opener" issue. Openers are not intended to hold a heavy door up by brute force, and will probably shear the (usually plastic) gear teeth under excessive loads, leading to the door crashing down and possibly injuring/killing someone.

Get the mechanicals sorted out (use a reputable company, not a guy who does a poor job), or have the whole door replaced (I'm fond of a nice insulated steel door, myself) with a properly suspended door that can be easily operated by hand. Then connect the opener to it.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not for a couple of reasons:

1. It seems unlikely that a 1.25 HP motor will fit where a 1/3 HP motor was designed.  So that alone might make fitting the new motor impossible.
2. Assuming you can get it mounted physically, it's likely that the electronics, which are designed and sized to handle the power needs of a 1/3 HP motor will be overloaded with a 1.25 HP motor and be damaged, either immediately or within a short while.
3. The mechanical design of the other parts driven by the motor are likely to be damaged by the much more powerful 1.25 HP motor.

Additionally, it sounds like your root problem is an improperly installed spring.  I recommend that your next step is to get that sorted out which may make the opener issue moot.

I think your best bet would be to scrap the one you have now and get a complete door opener model that is rated to operate the door you have.